# Need to display image from mysql database to fpdf

Tags: php, mysql, image, blob, fpdf

A have image save in mysql database as bolb and I wish to display it out in fpdf using php. I'm having problem doing this as I am very new to fpdf. I really need help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You will need this extension to FPDF: http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script45.php

[updated]

```
$query = "SELECT imageField FROM yyy WHERE ...";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$image = $row['imageField'];

$pdf->MemImage($image, 50, 30);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have tried that, but i believe that only works if the image is saved into host. but my current image are saved in mysql (blob).

Comment: That's exactly what this script is for. You need to load your blob into a variable and use `MemImage($blob, ...)` method

Comment: I'm sorry but I still do not really understand and would like to have your guidedence... Refer to you earlier use of extension. I have copr the example...

Comment: //Load an image into a variable
$logo = file_get_contents('logo.jpg');
//Output it
$pdf->MemImage($logo, 50, 30);

Comment: My image is stored in mysql data base where my database name is xxx and table is yyy and image as bolb. So may I know how can I call out the image.. your example is "logo.jpg". but I don think I can use that right?? Thank you

Comment: Thank you for the good reply Mchl, but I'm sorry to say that I have a new error message: Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDF::MemImage() in /home/content/x/y/z/nettwork/html/magnit/view_pdf.php on line 113

Comment: If I may tell you more, my tabe is set as CREATE TABLE `upload_photo_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `can_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `type` varchar(30) default NULL,
  `size` int(11) default NULL,
  `content` mediumblob,
  `upload_date` char(30) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

Comment: And I have wriiten as you guidence as :                         $sql = "SELECT * FROM upload_photo_table WHERE can_id = $char";
$result = mysqli_query($cxn,$sql)
 or die("Invalid query: ");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$image = $row2['content'];
$pdf->MemImage($image, 50, 30);

Comment: Did you add the `VariableStream` class to your code, and extend the FPDF with the code from the link above? Looks like you didn't.

Comment: Can you guide me on this please.

Comment: Everything is explaied in the link above. If you have trouble with it, I'd suggest asking for help in FPDF forums. There's usually someone hanging around, and It's a lot more comfortable for such conversations than StackOverflow's Q-A system.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Alternatively
//1) Put the class VariableStream inside your php file instead of declaring it
//--------------------------

enter code here

class VariableStream
{
    var $varname;
    var $position;

    function stream_open($path, $mode, $options, &$opened_path)
    {
        $url = parse_url($path);
        $this->varname = $url['host'];
        if(!isset($GLOBALS[$this->varname]))
        {
            trigger_error('Global variable '.$this->varname.' does not exist', E_USER_WARNING);
            return false;
        }
        $this->position = 0;
        return true;
    }

    function stream_read($count)
    {
        $ret = substr($GLOBALS[$this->varname], $this->position, $count);
        $this->position += strlen($ret);
        return $ret;
    }

    function stream_eof()
    {
        return $this->position >= strlen($GLOBALS[$this->varname]);
    }

    function stream_tell()
    {
        return $this->position;
    }

    function stream_seek($offset, $whence)
    {
        if($whence==SEEK_SET)
        {
            $this->position = $offset;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function stream_stat()
    {
        return array();
    }
}
//----------------------------------------------------
//2) open and read your mysql longblob that contains your binary data from your image
//in my case the function declaration is this

function showImage($cdImg) {

Global $pdf; 
    //declare your pdf class
    //Connects the way you do. this case assigned as $odbc_conn

   $query = 'SELECT cd_img, ds_img, bin_img FROM tb_img WHERE cd_img = '.$cdImg;

$result= mysqli_query($odbc_conn, $query);

  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

  if (!empty($row["bin_img"]))
  {

    //IF your data is encoded
    //$data=base64_decode($row['bin_img']);
    //
        $data=$row['bin_img'];
   }

   mysqli_free_result($result);

   mysqli_close($odbc_conn);

    stream_wrapper_register('var', 'VariableStream');

$x=null;

$y=null;

$w=0;

$h=0;

$link='';


        //Display the image contained in $data
       $v = 'img'.md5($data);
        $GLOBALS[$v] = $data;
        $a = getimagesize('var://'.$v);
        if(!$a)
        $pdf->Error('Invalid image data');
        $type = substr(strstr($a['mime'],'/'),1);
        $pdf->Cell(1);
        $pdf->Cell(26, 1, '', '', 0,'L');
        $pdf->Cell(150, 1, '', '', 1,'L');
        //650=150 choose your options for height and width
        //845=156
        //$xc=ceil((676-$a['width'])/2);

        $pdf->Image('var://'.$v, 44, $y, 150, 0, $type, $link);

        unset($GLOBALS[$v]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the  code`$pdf->Image('http://www.elwebmaster.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/PHP-logo.png',30,278,8);` or if in your root directory `$pdf->Image($_SESSION['raiz'].'imagens/tsunami.jpg',150,285,12);`

you could have blob saved images in your sql data base then use `$pdf->Image($_SESSION['raiz'].'imagens/picture.php?id=1',150‌​,285,12);` where id is the database index and picture.php is the file thats retrieve the image that you want to show