# Converting a base64 string into a image, without save it on disk using php

Tags: php, image, save, base64, fpdf

I'm working on generating dinamic PDF with FPDF.
Now I'm stuck in this point, I send from Javascript a base64 image containing a Graph.

This is my code inside the FPDF class for insert an image.

```
function Grafici ($image)
{   

    list($type, $image) = explode(';', $image);
    list(, $image)      = explode(',', $image);
    $data = base64_decode($image);
    file_put_contents('/tmp/image.png', $data);
    $this->Image('/tmp/image.png', 10, 63, 100);

}
```

As you can see, i'm saving the image on the server disk.
Is there a way to avoid the saving? If i remove the file_put_contents command and I put directly $data on $this-> Image($data, 10, 63, 100); FPDF return the error:

> FPDF error: Image file has no extension and no type was specified:

Comment: Apparently there is an extension which can do this. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3742060/505722) may help.

Comment: @Jim you're my hero! This works perfectly!

Many Thanks!!!